# Azure API Management - require approval of new developer signup

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

As we all know, the Azure API Management provides a developer portal.  You can change the way that users login to the portal with AAD, Facebook, ...  I understand how to configure those options.

I don't want new developers to have automatic access to the portal.  I want to review the signup and approve them before they get access.  How do I implement this approval process for new users?

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly this can be done via the product, require subscription approval... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-add-products#create-and-publish-a-product-1

Comment: you can require approval for subscription to a product, but this won't prevent someone from creating an account and signing into the site.

Answer (score 1):

User registration can be delegated to a third-party system: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-setup-delegation

Answer (score 0):

It's I remember correctly this can be done via the product, require subscription approval